# If $A_1,A_2,…,A_n$ are independent then $A_1^c,A_2^c,…,A_n^c$ are also independent.

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, independence

Let $A_1,A_2,…,A_n$ be events in a probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$.

If $A_1,A_2,…,A_n$ are independent then  $A_1^c,A_2^c,…,A_n^c$ are also independent, (where $A^c = \Omega \setminus A$).

I have found a proof by induction for this exercise, however, I have not been able to understand the conclusion of the proof, which I have marked in red. That is, why can it be immediately concluded that $A_1^c , A_2^c ,..., A_{k+1}^c$ are independent? I would really appreciate if someone can give me a clear explanation of what happens in that conclusion.

**Proof by induction.**

*Basis for the Induction*.

If $A_1$ and $A_2$ are independent then  $A_1^c$ and $A_2^c$ are independent.

Assume $A_1$ and $A_2$ are independent. Then
\begin{align*}
P(A_1^c \cap A_2^c) 
&= 1 - P(A_1 \cup A_2) \\
&= 1 - P(A_1) - P(A_2) + P(A_1 \cap A_2) \\
&= 1 - P(A_1) - P(A_2) + P(A_1)P(A_2) \\
&= (1-P(A_1))(1-P(A_2)) \\
&= P(A_1^c)P(A_2^c).
\end{align*}

*Induction Hypothesis.*

This is our induction hypothesis:

If $A_1,A_2,…,A_k$ are independent then $A_1^c,A_2^c,…,A_k^c$ are independent.

Then we need to show:

If $A_1,A_2,…,A_{k+1}$ are independent then $A_1^c,A_2^c,…,A_{k+1}^c$ are independent.

*Induction Step*.

This is our induction step.

Suppose $A_1,A_2,…,A_{k+1}$ are independent.

Then:
\begin{align}
P\left( {\bigcap_{i = 1}^{k + 1} A_i}\right) &= P\left( \bigcap_{i=1}^{k}A_i \cap A_{k+1} \right) \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{k}P(A_i) \cdot P(A_{k+1})\\
&= P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}A_i\right) \cdot P(A_{k+1})
\end{align}

So we see that $\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}A_i$ and $A_{k+1}$ are independent.

So $\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}A_i$ and $A_{k+1}^c$ are independent.

$\color{red}{\text{So, from the above results, we can see that} A_1^c,A_2^c,…,A_{k+1}^c \text{are independent}}.$

Comment: Does https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3278839/a-k-k-1n-independent-iff-p-left-bigcap-k-1n-b-k-right-pro help?

Comment: Hi: In the second to last sentence ( the sentence right above the line in red ), there should be a complement of the intersection. Does it make more sense then ? Not sure if you left it out or the book left it out  but it definitely does not make sense as is.

Comment: @markleeds According to what you say, if $\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{k} A_i \right)^c$ and $A_{k+1}^c$ are independent, can I conclude that $A_1^c , A_2^c ,..., A_{k+1}^c$ are independent? Why?

Comment: Hi: That's how proof by induction works. First  you prove the statement is true  for a simplle case like say i = 2,  Then you show that,  if the statement is true for $i = n$, then  this implies that the same is true for $i = ( n+1)$.  So, that's what was done here. It was shown that the statement is true for the i = 2 case and that it being true for i = n implies that its true for i = n+1.  Therefore, the proof is complete.  I hope that clarifies things. If that's not clear, maybe google for "proof by induction" because my explanation may not be the greatest.

Comment: @markleeds Exactly! I understand the dynamics of the test; what I have not been able to understand is the inductive step. I got that $\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}A_i\right)^c$ and $A_{k+1}^c$ are independent, just before the line in red; however, I think I should prove that $P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{k+1}A_i^c \right) = \prod_{i=1}^{k+1}P(A_i^c)$. How can I conclude that from the above?

Comment: @Inquirer: Let me look at the proof closer when I get back late tonight. I don't have time right now to do that. Or maybe the person who showed it will jump in and explain it more clearly. ( I still think there two typos at the end of  which make it confusing ).  We shall see. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @markleeds I agree. I appreciate if you do.

Comment: @Inquirer: I apologize for delay. I will definitely try to answer more clearly tonight. Something came up.

Comment: @markleeds No problem. I will be waiting for your answer because I'm very interested in knowing your ideas about this situation, which I have not been able to resolve yet.

Answer (score 1):

Partial attempt:

Let $B_1 := \bigcap_{i=1}^k A_i^c$ and $B_2 := A_{k+1}^c$.

\begin{align}
P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{k+1} A_i^c\right)
&= P(B_1 \cap B_2)
\\
&= 1 - P(B_1^c \cup B_2^c)
\\
&= 1 - P(B_1^c) - P(B_2^c) + P(B_1^c \cap B_2^c)
\\
&\overset{*}{=} 1 - P(B_1^c) - P(B_2^c) + P(B_1^c) P(B_2^c)
\\
&= P(B_1) P(B_2)
\\
&= P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{k} A_i^c\right) P(A_{k+1}^c)
\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{k+1} P(A_i^c).
\end{align}

It remains to verify the starred equality $P(B_1^c \cap B_2^c) = P(B_1^c) P(B_2^c)$.

\begin{align}
P(B_1^c \cap B_2^c)
&= P\left(
\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^k A_i^c\right)^c
\cap A_{k+1}
\right)
\\
&= P\left(
\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i\right)
\cap A_{k+1}
\right)
\\
&\overset{?}{=} P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i \right) P(A_{k+1})
\\
&= P(B_1^c) P(B_2^c).
\end{align}

For the "?" equality, I think you can show this by writing $\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i$ as the disjoint union of intersections of $A_1, \ldots, A_k, A_1^c, \ldots, A_k^c$.

Comment: I will attempt to complete your approach ( but if it was easy you would have completed it yourself so no guarantees and I don't have much time right now  ) but below is a clever approach that doesn't use induction in case you and Inquirer are interested. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192151/prove-complements-of-independent-events-are-independent

Answer (score 0):

Hi Inquirer: My apologies for the delay. I've had a lot going on so I just got back to this today.

I figured I'd put it in an answer since you get more space that way.

So, you agree that you proved the statement for $i = 2$ case, right. You showed that if $A_1$ and $A_2$ are independent, then $A^{c}_{1}$ and $A^{c}_{2}$ are independent. So, what induction says is that, if we have proven the statement for $i = 2$ and then we can show that, it being true for $i = 2$, implies that it is also true for the $i = 3$ case, then we are done with the proof by an induction argument.

So, let us assume that $A_{1}, A_{2}$ and $A_3$ are independent. We want to show that, given that the statement is true for $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$, then this implies that $A^{c}_{1}, A^{c}_{2}$ and $A^{c}_{3}$ are independent.

So, what we can do for clarity is let $k = 2$ and then use the same proof that you used in your question.

\begin{align}
P\left( {\bigcap_{i = 1}^{2 + 1} A_i}\right) &= P\left( \bigcap_{i=1}^{2}A_i \cap A_{2+1} \right) \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{2}P(A_i) \cdot P(A_{2+1})\\
&= P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{2}A_i\right) \cdot P(A_{2+1}) \\
&= P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{2}A_i\right) \cdot P(A_{3})
\end{align}

Next we can use the trick of letting $A_{1}^{*} = \bigcap_{i=1}^{2}A_i$ and letting $A_{2}^{*} = A_{3}$.

So, what we have shown above is that that $A^{*}_1$ and $A^{*}_2$ are independent. But we then know that (because it's already been proven for $i = 2$) that $A^{c*}_{1}$ and $A^{c*}_{2}$ are independent. But $A^{c*}_{1} = \bigcap_{i=1}^{2}A^{c}_i$  and $A^{*c}_{2} = A^{c}_{3}$ so this
means that $A^{c}_{1}, A^{c}_{2}$ and $A^{c}_{3}$ are independent. This is because $\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{2}A^{c}_i\right) \bigcap A^{c}_{3} = \bigcap_{i=1}^{3}A^{c}_i$.

So, what we have shown is that the $i = 2$ case being true implies that the $i = 3$ case is also true so, since this argument holds for $k = 2$, it implies that it also holds for any value of $k$. So we have proved the statement using induction. Does that make sense ? If not, let me know what part doesn't and I'll try to explain it more clearly.

Comment: Given "$A_1^*$ and $A_2^*$ are independent," I can see how "$(A_1^*)^c$ and $(A_2^*)^c$ are independent" follows from the $i=2$ case. But $(A_1^*)^c =\left( \bigcap_i A_i\right)^c$ is not the same as $A_1^{c*} := \bigcap_i A_i^c$.

Comment: @angryavian: thanks for your comment.  I don't have time to look at this right now but if you want to fix my proof or add your own correct proof, it's appreciated. otherwise, I'll get back to it and try to fix it as time permits.  Inquirer: The same goes for you if you see a fix.

Comment: @markleeds Thanks for your argument, however $A_{1}^{*c} = \left(\bigcap_{i}A_i\right)^c = \bigcup_{i}A_i^c \neq \bigcap_{i}A_i^c$

Comment: yes. I noticed that earlier from angryvian's comment. I have an email into someone who wrote a document which said that they knew of an induction argument but it's tricky. So I asked him where it was because I can't find one or construct one. I apologize for not being able to get it right. If this person gets back to me, I'll get back to this thread. Or if come up with something, I'll get back to this thread. I'm thinking that somehow using Demorgan's law as angryvian hinted but so far no success.